Calling a named range without naming the workbook
My macro is currently working with the below line:
Range("Fee_Calculator.xlsm!Modelling_Labour_WBS").Copy

I want to remove the reference to the workbook name but I'm not sure how.
I think I need to use ThisWorkbook but I can't work out how to get this working. My VBA skills are VERY basic and this one is beyond me!

ThisWorkbook.Names("Modelling_Labour_WBS").RefersToRange.Copy

You can also use the square bracket syntax to refer to a named range: [Modelling_Labour_WBS].Copy
